# mysql_insert_id() echos 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, mysql-insert-id

I am not the first to have this problem but the solutions of the others don't work.
This script always returns 0 for mysql_insert_id(); I am using multiple primary keys.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Price,Description,User)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_SESSION['user']."');";
$result = $GLOBALS['DB']->query($sql);
echo mysql_insert_id();
echo '<div class="saving">';
if($result){
echo "Saved!";
} else{
echo("Saving failed");
} echo '</div>';
}
```

I already tried `mysql_insert_id($link)`, where I linked `$link` to a `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_insert_id($GLOBALS['DB']->MySQLiObj)`

My $GLOBAL['DB']

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['DB']))$DB = new \System\Database\MySQL(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_BENUTZER,MYSQL_KENNWORT,MYSQL_DATENBANK,MYSQL_PORT);
```

My MySQL class:

```
public $MySQLiObj = null;

function __construct($server, $user, $password, $db, $port = '3306')
{

    $this->MySQLiObj = new \mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db, $port);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Keine Verbindung zum MySQL-Server möglich.";
        trigger_error("MySQL-Connection-Error", E_USER_ERROR);
        die();
    }

    $this->query("SET NAMES utf8");
}
```

Comment: What database abstraction layer are you using ($GLOBALS['DB']) ?

Comment: @JohnConde it doesn't say anything `mysql_error();` (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, use `mysqli` features instead

Comment: @user2972107 do you mean I should use `mysqli::$insert_id`?

Comment: yes...no harm in keeping your code upto-date on standards and performance!! :)

Comment: @user2972107 `mysqli::$insert_id` doesn't work either.

Comment: And I am using multiple primary keys.

Comment: Can you echo `$sql` and post it here?

Comment: use `die()` command to print your `$sql` and try manually executing the statement...that might help to understand the prob!

Comment: @CasperAndréCasse `INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Preis,Beschreibung,Benutzer) VALUES ('Test','0','Test','1');`

Comment: @user2972107 @CasperAndréCasse Inserting into the DB works fine, but I only get 0 form the `mysql_insert_id()` statement, maybe because I have multiple primary keys?

Comment: Maybe `PersistentConnections` is disabled in your phpMyAdmin config file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally made it!
In my Class I added the function insert_id() and then added the insert_id variable locally.

```
public function insert_id()
{
    $result = $this->MySQLiObj->insert_id;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is failing because you are using the [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) `desc` without ticks. As a result the INSERT fails and thus no ID is returned.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Price,Desc,User)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_SESSION['user']."');";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Price,`Desc`,User)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_SESSION['user']."');";
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) explains this very well:

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, **0 if the previous query does not generate an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value**, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

It is possible that your table does not have any column set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. `mysql_insert_id()` will return `0` in such cases.

<sup>Usual disclaimer: `mysql_` functions are deprecated and are soon to be removed. Stop using them and switch to MySQLi / PDO instead.</sup>

Comment: @JSHelp: Add `echo mysql_error();` after the `mysql_insert_id()` statement. What does it output?

Comment: @JSHelp: What happens when you try to execute the MySQL query manually? (using phpMyAdmin or similar)

Answer (score 1):

The core problem here is that you're using `mysqli` for your `query()` call, but then trying to use the `mysql_insert_id()` function.

Please note that the `mysqli` and `mysql` functions are two entirely separate libraries, and are incompatible with each other.

If you're using `mysqli` in one part of your code, you *must* use `mysqli` for all other DB-related code as well, otherwise they will not work together.

So you must use the `mysqli::$insert_id` property instead.

You mentioned in the question that you can access your connection object as `$GLOBALS['DB']->connection`. In that case, you should be able to write your code as follows:

```
$newId = $GLOBALS['DB']->connection->insert_id;
```

I hope that helps.

PS: While I'm here, I'll add that you should avoid putting `$_POST` variables directly into your query string like that. It's very poor practice and has some dangerous security implications. You should look into using `mysqli->prepare()` and `mysqli->bind_param()` to add the parameters for your queries instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the POST, I would have (and I will) change it later, after the sql connection and all that works.

Comment: Also note that I cannot access `$GLOBALS['DB']->connection`, where I actually meant `$GLOBALS['DB']->MySQLiObj` (see my question). I also tried `mysqli_insert_id()` and `$GLOBALS['DB']->MySQLiObj->insert_id` (see comments) they all don't work.

Comment: You say "they all didn't work", but please elaborate on that: what errors are you getting from them?

Comment: Just to be clear, the first part of my answer remains true regardless: even if `mysqli->insert_id` doesn't work exactly as I stated in the answer or per your tests, this **is** the direction you need to go to find the answer. You *cannot* use the old `mysql_insert_id()` and expect to get a value from it if you've used `mysqli` to do the insert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phpMyAdmin, maybe PersistentConnections is disabled in the config file (`config.inc.php`).

If this is the case, change it to:

```
$cfg['PersistentConnections'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

**desc** is a reserved word in mysql, so you need escape it with **``**

```
INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Price,`Desc`,User)
```

[list of reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: I changed that, didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

mutliple errors i guess :

```
mysqli_insert_id($con) //$con is connection obj
```

Sql query : extra `semi-colon` in sql-query end and reserved keyword DESC used

```
 "INSERT INTO Produkte (Name,Price,`Desc`,User)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_SESSION['user']."')";
```

Refer manual :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php